# input type text does not work on iphone

Tags: iphone, input, forms

I have a very strange issue in which text input on [this web page](http://www.5.fishfeedingchart.appspot.com) doesn't work on iPhone, i.e., the iPhone keyboard does not pop up when using mobile Safari.  Safari debug mode provides no messages.

The textbox works fine on Android, standard IE, Firefox, etc.

Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: It's not a case of text inputs are buggy in Safari so what's the magic answer here. You need to break the problem down and give code examples... there's hardly a jot of markup in the source on your site so you're basically asking members to debug a bunch of minified JS on your behalf.

Comment: I solved my own problem and will share the answer in case others have a similar issue.

I had the following references to Javascript that were not being used.

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/popup.js"></script>

Removing these solved the problem.

Comment: @user1527312 Answer your question properly and mark your answer as accepted answer. Regards